# C# Networkstream reads nothing

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

Just trying to use Networkstream, and this is a simple code i wrote:

Client side:

```
       TcpClient c = new TcpClient();
        c.Connect("10.0.0.4", 10);
       NetworkStream ns = c.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("first");
        byte[] buffer2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("second");
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
       stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Write(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length);
        stream.CopyTo(ns);
```

This is the server side:

```
        TcpListener tl = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10);
        tl.Start();
        TcpClient c = tl.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream   ns = new NetworkStream(c.Client);
        byte[] buff = new byte[5];
        ns.Read(buff,0,buff.Length);
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);
        MessageBox.Show(result);
```

**only when i close the entire application the `MessageBox` line is  executed** , and im always getting a blank messagebox! which mean `result` doesnt contain nothing...
Any help?

Comment: @Eser nope. It doesnt solve any of the 2 problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client `stream` is positioned at the very end of the stream. Therefore, `CopyTo` has nothing left to copy.

Use `stream.Position = 0;` before copying.

Also, you don't seem to be aware of the fact that socket reads (in fact any stream read) can return less bytes than were requested (at least one). Your reading code must account for that. TCP does not preserve message boundaries.

Comment: yeah i know that.. thanks. it was just an example for a known size of data!. it worked!

Comment: may i ask if udp does preserve the boundaries?

Comment: It does but it drops messages. If you want to send messages use a higher-level stack such as http, wcf, or length prefixed protobuf.

Comment: im just working on a screen sharing app, which runs very fast and send frames to the server. somtimes it can get up to 130kb(with no compression). would you recommend udp? thanks! i appreicate your help.

Comment: That answer would be quite long. Maybe you should ask a new question whether UDP is better for screen sharing. It can be.

Comment: You cannot simply replace `TCP` with `UDP` -- Also for a screensharing app you can use both. Simple functionality should go through `TCP`and the actual screen-sharing image would be send over `UDP`. `TCP` is safer than `UDP` so using that for core functionality would be the best, where `UDP` may lose data during send/receive and thus you could ex. be missing a few pixels of the screen.

Comment: @Bauss alright.. i guess it wont be so  crucial.. what do you mean `few pixels?` in what it depended?

Comment: With `a few pixel` I mean that `UDP` does not guarantee for all data to be sent/received thus you might end up losing bytes which could be a few pixels in case of sending an image.