# c# - networkstream read and write

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

good day all

I am going over some network programming to implement with a larger application, but for basics, I am creating a simple network chat server client application with the help of this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using)

**what should happen:**

When receiving the data from the client, the message box pops up showing a socket connection to my PC ip address with port, but

**Problem:**

the messagebox which displays the message sent is empty (aka ""), I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Advice?

*had a look at this, but I do not think this is appropriate for my situation* [network stream with buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226972/c-sharp-networkstream-reads-nothing)

client (sends data)

```
        const int _PORT = 80;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void sendText(string _reciever_ip, string _MESSAGE)
        {
            TcpClient _sender = new TcpClient(_reciever_ip, _PORT);
            try
            {
                Stream s = _sender.GetStream();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
                sw.WriteLine(_MESSAGE);
                s.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
            _sender.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sendText(inputT_IP.Text, inputT_Msg.Text);
        }
```

server (recieves data)

```
    const int _PORT = 80;

    static List<string> _ipaddress_list = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void recieveText(string _IPADDRESS)
    {
        //open a listener for a tcp client, to the same for UDp client
        TcpListener _reciever_client = new     TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(_IPADDRESS), _PORT); //how would you listen for a     connection from any port?
        _reciever_client.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Socket _listener_socket = _reciever_client.AcceptSocket();
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Recieving from : " +     _listener_socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                Stream _net_stream = new NetworkStream(_listener_socket);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_net_stream);
                MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadLine());
                //richTextBox1.AppendText();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
            _listener_socket.Close();
        }
    }

    void GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                _ipaddress_list.Add(ip.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetLocalIPAddress();
        foreach (string item in _ipaddress_list)
        {
            (new Thread(() => recieveText(item))).Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try changing `s.Close();` to `sw.Close();` which should flush the streamwriter and close the underlying socket.

Comment: Port 80 is probably blocked.  Use a Port number > 10,000

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson your answer is correct, please post if for me to accept this answer, why does this work, if I may ask it in such a manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A StreamWriter buffers writes, so your code;

```
Stream s = _sender.GetStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
sw.WriteLine(_MESSAGE);
s.Close();
```

...actually writes to the StreamWriter's in memory buffer and closes the socket before the data has been passed from the StreamWriter to the network.

If you instead close the StreamWriter;

```
Stream s = _sender.GetStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
sw.WriteLine(_MESSAGE);
sw.Close();
```

...`Close()` actually flushes the buffer to the underlying socket, and *then* closes the underlying socket after the data has been sent.